# Loader is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#sql').on ('click',function() {

       $('#loaderImg').show(); 

     });
    </script>
```

And html

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center"></h1>
  <div id="loaderImg" style="display:none;background-color:white;width:100%;height:660px;">
     <img src="25.gif" alt="loader1" style="height:100px; width:100px;position:relative;left:500px;top:300px"></div>
     <input type="submit"  name="sql"  id="sql" onclick="myFunction1()" value="Import Database"   class="btn btn-danger"">
```

I have a button 'import database'.When i clicks the button the loader should be shown until the loading complete.But my problem is the  loader image disappear suddenly after displays for a second.How can i solve this??

Comment: how is this a php question and what's the relation to a database?

Comment: Import database is for downloading database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `onclick` from button.

***code need to be:-***

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center"></h1>
    <div id="loaderImg" style="display:none;background-color:white;width:100%;height:660px;">
        <img src="25.gif" alt="loader1" style="height:100px; width:100px;position:relative;left:500px;top:300px"></div>
        <input type="submit"  name="sql"  id="sql" value="Import Database"  class="btn btn-danger">

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#sql').on ('click',function() {

   $('#loaderImg').show(); 

 });
</script>
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$('#sql').on ('click',function() {

 $('#loaderImg').show(); 

});
```

```css
#loaderImg{
display:none;
background-color:white;
width:100%;
height:100px;
}

img{
height:100px; 
width:100px;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center"></h1>
    <div id="loaderImg">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" alt="loader1">
     </div>
<input type="submit"  name="sql"  id="sql" value="Import Database"   class="btn btn-danger">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I tried your code on Codepen and it worked well. The only problem is, there is no closing  on your html. And after you close your container div, loading gif should play until you hide it again.

So my suggestions are, remove `onclick` from button because you are not using it, add closing `</div>` at the end of your code.

I have no idea how big your project is but just in case if another plugin or javascript code interfers with your `<input id='#sql'>` element,

you may try to use `$(document).on ('click', '#sql' ,function() {.....})`

instead of `$('#sql').on ('click',function() {...});`